# To generate basic bar graphs using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a newbie to python. Please help me with this error.My idea is to generate a bar chart between cancer types and females. whereas, cancers on x-axis and females on the y-axis.In my dataset list of cancers are in a first column and females in second column. My code goes here:

```
from pylab import *
import csv
import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cancers = [] 
females = []

readFile = open('DeathEst.csv', 'r').read()
eachLine = readFile.split('\n')
```

for line in eachLine:

```
  split = line.split(';')
  cancers.append(split[0])
  females.append(split[0])

pos = arange(len(cancers))+.5
barh(pos, females, align='center', color='#b8ff4c')
yticks(pos,name)
plt.show()


Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "death.py", line 20, in <module>
  barh(pos, females, align='center', color='#b8ff4c')
 File "C:\Users\.....\Desktop\Python34\lib\sitepackages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2533, in barh
 ret = ax.barh(bottom, width, height=height, left=left, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\......\Desktop\Python34\lib\sitepackages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 5180, in barh
 bottom=bottom, orientation='horizontal', **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\......\Desktop\Python34\lib\sitepackages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 5047, in bar
 if w < 0:
 TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Comment: Please indent code snipplets (and also the Exception stack trace) with four spaces. This will neatly format them, making the question readable.

Comment: You can also select all your code after you paste it in, then click the curly braces { } button to highlight it as a code block. Pls go back and edit your post so we can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Your lists named cancers and females are both holding string elements, and not integers. Matplotlib doesn't know what to do with that.